# Chrome debugger shows warnings count without details

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Sorry for such a basic question, but I cannot figure it out:

The Google Developper Tool shows me a warning icon on the bottom left, but when I click on it, no warnings are displayed.
How can I display these warnings ? Is there a setting that is wrong or is Chrome just messed up on my machine ?

In this example I see that there are 12 warnings, but non of them is showing, no matter if I filter by `all`, `warnings` or any other.

[image: Chome debugger with warnings]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The blue "filter" icon (for me, it looks like a torch) is showing that you are filtering out some event types. It is probably `CSS` which I think defaults to _filtered out_. The _All , Errors, Warnings, Logs, Debug_ only control which logging levels are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have no any filter active on the search field just over that icon.

Comment: An active filter displays with **no tick and no checkbox**, what is somehow unexpected.